# Не работает @include в @section

Tags: laravel, blade

Пытаюсь подключить Navbar `admin_nav` к секции `'content'`, но получаю пустую страницу. При том, что при подключении в родительском файле `admin_app` все работает корректно. Что я делаю не так?

admin_app.blade.php

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/all.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
</head>
<body class="">
<main class="text-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-W8fXfP3gkOKtndU4JGtKDvXbO53Wy8SZCQHczT5FMiiqmQfUpWbYdTil/SxwZgAN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-skAcpIdS7UcVUC05LJ9Dxay8AXcDYfBJqt1CJ85S/CFujBsIzCIv+l9liuYLaMQ/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.blade.php

```php
@extends('layouts.admin_app')

@section('title')Авторизация@endsection

@section('content')
    @include('Inc.admin_nav')
    ...
    ...
@endsection
```

admin_nav.blade.php

```html
@section('admin_nav')
    <div class=" col-2 d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 p-3 bg-light">
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: В `admin_nav.blade.php` подключается код который ищет секцию `admin_nav`, а её вроде как нет. Попробуй из этого файла убрать `@section('admin_nav')` чтобы вставлялся сраху код или наоборот добавить где-нибудь `@yield('admin_nav')` чтоб он видел куда вставлять.

Comment: Ещё можно в `admin_nav.blade.php` закрыть секцию не `@endsection`, а `@show`. Это если планируете иногда полностью "перекрыть" секцию `admin_nav`.